# Linear relation inside of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $d(P,l)$ be distance between point $P$ and line $l$. Inside triangle $ABC$ there are points $D$ and $E$, for which
$$
d(D,AC)+d(D,BC)=d(D,AB),
$$
$$
d(E,AC)+d(E,BC)=d(E,AB).
$$
Prove that $d(X,AC)+d(X,BC)=d(X,AB)$ for any point $X$ on segment $DE$.

Looks like there is a laborious analytical proof relying on the coordinate method. But could there be an easier solution, that is also purely geometric?

Comment: Have you drawn it out?  Where did you find this problem statement?  What geometric work have you done to crack this?

Comment: @amWhy Official solution for one of the IMO problems. They use this without giving a proof, simply saying that they rely on linearity of the relation in variable $X$. I have drawn it out, but have no idea how to approach this geometrically...

Comment: I can't answer the question of whether there's a purely geometric proof, but do you know what "linearity" means here? That argument is worth understanding and is fast once one is comfortable with the terms.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I don't. I was actually hoping I would understand it from a geometric proof...

Comment: Try to start with this (forget E, D for the moment): exactly one point on AC and exactly one on BC verify the condition, denote the points P, Q. Then explore the segment PQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is as simple as it gets:

[image]

It's given that:

$$d_1+d_2=d_3$$

$$e_1+e_2=e_3$$

Introduce: $DX=u$ for some point $X\in DE$.

$$x_1=d_1+\frac{u}{DE}(e_1-d_1)$$

$$x_2=d_2+\frac{u}{DE}(e_2-d_2)$$

$$x_1+x_2=d_1+\frac{u}{DE}(e_1-d_1)+d_2+\frac{u}{DE}(e_2-d_2)=$$

$$x_1+x_2=(d_1+d_2)+\frac{u}{DE}((e_1+e2)-(d_1+d2))=$$

$$x_1+x_2=d_3+\frac{u}{DE}(e_3-d_3)=$$

$$x_1+x_2=x_3$$

Yes, it's all about "linearity".